# Fix UITableViewController offset due to UIRefreshControl in iOS 7

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm setting up a UIRefreshControl in my uitableviewcontroller, but there is a big gap between the navbar and the top of the uitableview. Playing with 'adjust scroll view insets' doesn't help, as the controller will underlay the navbar at startup. I could disable 'under top bars', but I want that ability when scrolling. When poking around in the debugger, I noticed at various times the tableView.contentInset is offset by 82 points, which is different from the ususal 20/64 pt offset people talk about regarding the new ios7 bar behavior. What's going on here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a solution while poking around more; hope it saves someone a few hours!

I needed to instantiate my UIRefreshControl after `viewDidLoad:`, or avoid setting its `attributedTitle` in code at least until after that (e.g. if I enabled refreshing of the table in IB). Setting the string inside viewDidLoad: messes up iOS's layout of the control+tableview, but it's ok within `viewWillAppear:` or later once the geometry is set. And  I think 82 points is the height of the UIRefreshControl. Setting the refresh title in IB would've also avoided this problem, except that I was doing so in code because I didn't want to have to enable refreshing in IB all the time with each of my tables.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I was indeed setting my attributedTitle of my refresh control in viewDidLoad and it would break the layout if it was done too quickly (before VWA).

Comment: Wow, I've been struggling with this stupid uirefreshcontrol for hours.  Thanks for this!

Comment: Didn't work for me in viewWillAppear, but it worked in viewDidAppear

Comment: Hi :) also just in case, make sure you've added the [self.refreshControl endRefreshing] or self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() depending on which language you are using.

Comment: It was avoiding setting the attributedTitle that did it for me, I can even instantiate the UIRefreshControl in the init.